# Form.submit is not found in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

Code

html

```
<form id="myFrm" name="myFrm" action="/myApp/ProcessFrm" method="post">
    <input autofocus="autofocus" type="text" id="Location" name="Location" onkeydown="changetotab()" style="width: 4em" tabindex="1"  />
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit" id="submit" /> <br />
</form>
```

js

```
 function changetotab() {
            var charCode = (window.event.which) ? window.event.which : window.event.keyCode;

            if (charCode == 13 || charCode == 9) {
                if (document.myFrm.submit == undefined) {
                    alert("form submit can't be found")
                } else {
                    alert("form can be submitted");
                   document.myFrm.submit();
                }
            }
        }
```

What happens is that when the user pressed TAB or ENTER, document.myFrm.submit == undefined comes up false (so far so good); then something weird happens - when I get to document.myFrm.submit(); JS informs that this method is not found.

> 0x80020003 - JavaScript runtime error: Member not found.

What is happening here?

Note: I can't use Jquery, just in case you were wondering why I am using old style JS. This will run on the old devices that do not support Jquery.

Comment: did you try document.getElementById('myFrm') instead of document.myFrm?

Comment: or document.forms["myFrm"]

Comment: Just did try both - neither works. Trying not to rip my hair out. Let me reboot my Visual Studio.

Comment: nope, no luck..... any ideas would be welcome at this point

Comment: try loading the form once above the conditional statement.
var myFrm = document.getElementById("myFrm");

Comment: Before submitting do `alert(typeof document.myFrm.submit)`. What you see?

Comment: @Teemu - I see the word object printed out

Comment: the reason i said try loading the form once, into a variable, is so that you can start using it like myFrm.submit() instead of document.myFrm.submit() which is wrong (to my knowledge)

Comment: @Will, nothing works.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: @sarsnake Hence it's not a function. Considering some really old DOM, alerting `document.myFrm.submit.tagName` probably gives you `input` --> Boldewyn's answer should fix your problem.

Comment: did you try using Boldewyn's solution

Comment: @Teemu - thank you - I leafed through the properties and methods and submit was not one of them. Got me on the right track!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boldewyn/2rY2U/). What's going on here? Well, in the pre-DOM times, JavaScript created one property `foo` for each `input` with name `foo` on the `input`'s parent `form`:

```
form.foo.toString() === "HTMLInputElement";
```

This however, means, that, if you have an input element with name `submit`, the form's own `submit` method is overwritten. This behaviour has survived till today.

Now, your input has no `name` attribute. In this case, the behaviour is to deduce one from the `input`'s ID, if one is set. So basically, change the ID of the `input`, that's the most straight-forward way to deal with it:

```
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" id="submit_" />
```

There are lots of such subtleties, unfortunately. See [DOMLint](http://kangax.github.io/domlint/) for a good overview.

**Edit:** What to do, if you end up with a clobbered `submit` method and no way to change the HTML? Then fetch the submit method from the form's prototype and use that:

```
// form.submit() doesn't work, but this will:
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(form);
```

Comment: Yes. It's subtle and even experienced devs fall regularly for it.

Comment: It's never bitten me, but I have this 'don't use names that are already taken' rule kind of engrained into my head.  I treat things like that as keywords and leave them alone.

Comment: oh my. That's cruel - I normally don't use the old JS anymoer maybe that's why I haven't seen it yet. Thank you! I was ready to go nuts here!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (plain javascript):

```
document.getElementById('myFrm')
```